# access exchange 2003 calendars with vs2005+

Tags: visual-studio, exchange-server

I'm looking for a way to access Exchange 2003 calendars to add appointments.  I'm hoping to use an admin account and impersonate each user to add appointments which i'm pulling from an oracle database.  I've seen lots of examples for Exchange 2000 using cdox.dll which are exactly what I'm looking for but not an equivalent for 2003.  I have Exchange management tools installed on the development workstation.  Would I be able to download cdox.dll and use that?

Examples/links are greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Checkout stackoverflow for programming questions.  The answer will probably be that you should use the webdav interface.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same problem I'm banging my head against....

You can work with calendars using webdav:
http://golemlab.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/php-owa-2003-calendar-fun/

But to impersonate a user you need an admin account with access to his calendar folder.

From what I understand there is no way to set defaults permissions just for calendars **that are not created yet**.

Also please note that the Calendar folder name is dependant on the user client language (ex: "Calendar" for a user with an english outlook, "Calendario" for italians).

You can set permissions on existing calendars using a lot of different tools:
pfdavadmin is a microsoft endorsed one:

http://www.itexperience.net/2008/10/22/set-calendar-permissions-with-pfdavadmin/

or you can try setperm: 
http://www.amset.info/exchange/folderpermissions.asp

there are also some commercial products like folder permission manager:
http://www.symprex.com/products/folder-permissions-manager/

What I'd really wished was the possibility to set defaults calendar permissions on a server level , but this looks really not possible.